# Problem with pandas shift() when applying it on time-indexed time series

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I am trying to create a df containing lagged values of a time series for a supervised learning task using the pandas shift() method. When trying to set the periodsPast to a value greater than 2015, I get the following error when using the mock data in the snippet below:

```
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

When using the actual time series data, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (8760) into shape (8760,2015)
```

I changed the year of the first date in the index time range to 2017, the error appears if periodsPast is greater than 2017.

A code snippet (mock data):

```
import pandas as pd 

periodsPast = 2020 # any value above 2015 would give an error 

series = pd.Series(data = [i for i in range(1,10001)], index=pandas.date_range('2015-01-01 00:00:00',periods=10000,freq='H'))

dfLags = pd.DataFrame(data=None, index=series.index)
for t in range(0, periodsPast + 1):
    if t == 0:
        dfLags['t'] = series
    else:
        dfLags['t-'+str(t)] = series.shift(t)
```

It seems that for some reason the 2016th column can't be added. Also, it is no coincidence that the value at which the error is raised corresponds to the year of the first index.

Any ideas? It must be something very basic I am missing here. Many thanks.

Comment: try to do print `dfLags['t-2016']`, you will see that for some reasons it selects a specific range of rows where the year is 2016 instead of creating the column . Not sure why it does not through the same error on 2015 because it selects also only rows but anyway, if you can change the name of the column to `'t_'+str(t)` using `_` instead of `-`, it will work like expected

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion worked. I don't understand the behavior though.

Comment: it seems that the string 't-2016' is converted/interpreted as a timestamp at some point because the index is a DatetimeIndex. Why you got the error only on t-2016 and not other values, not sure yet